# trying to understand syntax

Tags: c++, c, macros, telegram

I'm reading the source code of Telegram Desktop application. There are a few lines defined like this:

```
#define DeclareSetting(Type, Name) DeclareReadSetting(Type, Name) \
inline void cSet##Name(const Type &Name) { \
    g##Name = Name; \
}
```

Could someone please explain what does this mean? I studied macro's but I couldn't understand this syntax. (please don't kill me if it's called something else kindly correct me by editing this.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated which particular part of these 3 lines, which tokens, you don't understand.

Comment: `##` is to concatenate tokens.

Comment: Check this out https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation

Comment: @mloskot unfortunately none of it. All I know is that this is some sort of macro but I haven't seen this type of definition before.